# Unrecognized escape sequence and Server Error in '/' Application in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, web, database-connection

This is the error that i have been trying to resolve.Can anyone be of help?
I just copied the thing written in quotes from the `web.config` file in asp.net but this error is not allowing for a proper connection.
The error is in this part `\myDatabase`.
I have tried replacing \myDatabase with `\\myDatabase` OR `/myDatabase` OR `//myDatabase`. Nothing worksbut nothing helped.web.config file is:-

```
 <configuration>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionString" 
connectionString="Data Source= (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\myDatabase.mdf;
Integrated Security=True"      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
 <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
 <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1"/>
</system.web>
 </configuration>
```

Comment: share your web.config file?

Comment: Did you tried adding `@` before the string? `SqlConnection(@"....")`?

Comment: yeah i tried using @ also